# UI looks different on iOS 5 an iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, uiswitch

I have UISwitch on my vie, loaded from xib. It's x position is bigger then zero and it looks ok on iOS 5 simulator. But when I try to run it on 4.3 simulator it looks like UISwitch's position is equal to zero

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As well as their change in appearance, `UISwitch`es have shrunk between iOS 4 and 5. Based on quick screenshot comparison, they were about 94pt wide and are now only 76pt. So if you have a switch that is, say, right aligned per the autosizing mask then it will extend further to the left in 4 than in 5.

Sadly there's very little you can do about that other than designing for 94pt widgets and accepting a bit of extra empty space under 5. Because the interface builder positions all things at exact pixel positions, rather than applying a layout logic, it's quite possible you'll have to do some manual programmatic adjustment.

Comment: I have all my UISwitches set to fixed top and left in the xib, but under iOS 4 they extend to the left and cover over the label. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If they're fixed left then I guess it's a case of the mechanisms that load the NIB calculating the appropriate frame for the iOS 5 size (based on the information in the NIB), setting that to the `UISwitch`s, and the switches in iOS 4 doing some sort of validation on that frame which results in them adjusting the width but being unsure exactly what to do with the origin.

Answer (score 1):

if ios 5 is the issue you can adjust the position based on the iOS version

```
     BOOL isIOS5 = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] >= 5;
```

Comment: As I understand, there is no way to do some stuff in xib to do the same?

Comment: Might be smarter to query the objects connected to your switch outlets for their size and adjust according to that, rather than (implicitly) hard coding the sizes for 4 and 5. So you'd perform no `systemVersion` check at all, just e.g. `someSwitch.frame.size.width`

Comment: @user564272 you should REALLY learn how to do it programatically. It's called programming for a reason.